# Change Font Size In Table Chart Widget

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there any way to change the font size in the Table-Chart Widget?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
.app-TableChart.Size12 .app-TableChart{
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good try. Unfortunately there are styles that apply directly to the cells so the font size does not inherit from the container. Try this:

```
.app-TableChart .google-visualization-table th,
.app-TableChart .google-visualization-table td {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!